# why some CSS properties are not there after running it

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am learning CSS and I have created a button which is a dropdown and then added `display:block` and `width:100%` to it, it does not do anything. also when I check page source after running it the properties are not even there so what am doing wrong.
this is button css :

```
.Dropdown-btn {
    display:block;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: inherit;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: black;
    font-family: inherit;
    background-color: inherit;
    padding: 13px 13px;
    margin: 0;
    width:100%;
}
```

and in page source it becomes :

```
.Dropdown-btn {
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: inherit;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: black;
    font-family: inherit;
    background-color: inherit;
    padding: 13px 13px;
    margin: 0;
}
```

also I have this dropdown button which works fine but when it toggles i want it to occupy all the space like above list item. how can i edit them?

[image]

also how to edit its dropdown items style after collapsing.

**Update :** now my CSS is getting reflected as expected after I cleared cached files in Microsoft edge.

Comment: It’s impossible for us to find what is wrong without seeing some code that demonstrates the problem. When you look in your dev tools what is it showing as the source file for that CSS?

Comment: i don't know what code to put here. In my site.css i added display:block property and build the sloution again and refreshed the web page. when i checked source code of that page in browser the display property was not there.

Comment: Hi @SalmanAbbas. Are you testing the updated CSS by uploading to a host then looking at it or are you testing it locally on your computer? If the first one then you will have to wait for the internet to catch up with regard to Cache Memory. This might take a couple of hours, it might take 12 hours. Or clear the Cache from your browser.

Comment: @CuteyfromCuteCode no I am testing it on my pc locally.

Comment: also it works perfectly in chrome not in edge